# Jquery Image Slide right to left

Tags: jquery, css, image, slide

I have three inline images which I'm wanting to slide from the right to left onload.

So when the user first comes to the page they will see each image slide from right to left one after another with about a second delay.

I guess this would use animate or css positioning?

You can use this: http://jsfiddle.net/RSk7n/8/ to try and get the effect.

All suggestions welcome!

Comment: You really just expect us to code your animation? What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: This is not constructive at all - please refrain from posting such comments.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/blackpla9ue/RSk7n/14/

```
function animateImgs(){
    $('ul li:not(.visible)')
        .first()
        .animate({'margin-left': '0px'},
                 1000, function(){
                     $(this).addClass('visible');
                     animateImgs();    
                });
}

animateImgs();
```

Make sure to add `overflow: hidden;` to your parent `ul` and `margin-left: 9999px;` to your `li`s